# Rails task in crontab error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

Using lubuntu 12.10, ruby 1.9.3p374(not RVM), Gem 1.8.23, and Rails 3.2.11

I've just recently installed the Whenever gem to create tasks that will run periodically. I created my task which runs every 1 minute and set it to run using:

```
whenever --update-crontab myproject --set environment=development
```

This command puts the following entry in my crontab:

```
* * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/myuser/projects/myproject && script/rails runner -e development '\''FileImporter.execute'\'' >> /home/myuser/projects/myproject/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
```

After waiting for some time I see that in my cron_log.log file spammed with the same exception:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require: cannot load such file -- bundler/script (LoadError)
```

However, when I run the following command manually in the terminal everything works just fine:

```
/bin/bash -l -c 'cd /home/myuser/projects/myproject && script/rails runner -e development '\''FileImporter.execute'\'' >> /home/myuser/projects/myproject/log/cron_log.log 2>&1'
```

Let me know if any more information is needed, I'm pretty new to the rails/linux world so I may have left some important stuff out.

Comment: No, also added my ruby and rails version to the top of my original post. Thanks

Comment: Can you change the task to use `bundle exec script/rails`?

Comment: It shows /bin/bash: bundle: command not found in the log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here on a similar question: [why #!/usr/bin/env ruby doesn't work in crontab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241572/why-usr-bin-env-ruby-doesnt-work-in-crontab)

Apparently PATH isn't set when the cron job executing so you have to set it in the crontab.

Running echo $PATH to see what PATH is set to and putting PATH=/my/path/values at the beginning of the crontab file fixes the issue.