# RoR: $bundle install => /usr/bin/env: ruby: not a directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu, path

I'm trying to install RoR with Mysql on Ubuntu and so far it has been a very painful and annoying experience.

Everything has been done with RVM, and upon trying to invoke:

```
$ rails new <some path> <some name> -d mysql
```

I get an error that MySQL is not installed, so I follow the instructions and run:

```
$ gem install bundler
=> Successfully installed bundler 1.2.3
```

From here the instructions via console to install MySQL are:

```
=> Run 'bundle install' to install missing gems.
$ bundle install
```

Trying to run this command results in the following output:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: not a directory
```

I would really appreciate some help, this is doing my head in since I just want to start programming. I expect this crap from Windows, not Ubuntu.

**Q: How do I fix it?**

Comment: Check out the answers for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241572/why-usr-bin-env-ruby-doesnt-work-in-crontab

Comment: Please explain how you installed Ruby.

Comment: @RyanBigg I did say everything has been done with RVM ^_^ - I solved the problem though and posted the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**

src: https://askubuntu.com/questions/182418/how-to-get-usr-bin-env-ruby-to-point-to-the-correct-ruby-environment

Adding:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM
```

to:

```
.bashrc
```

**THEN to fix MySQL installation errors I used the second solution (67 votes) on this question:**

[MySQL Install: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167598/mysql-install-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension)

**I hope this helps someone else in the future!**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running 'gem install mysql2'? Is mysql2 in your gem file?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` did the trick!

(Found here: http://phpcommit.wordpress.com/2012/04/06/install-apache2-php-rvmpassenger-ruby-in-ubuntu-12-04-linode/)